# automatic cpanel backup on shared hosting

Tags: linux, backup, cpanel

I have been looking for a way to backup complete cpanel including all the files and databases locally on the shared hosting.
No backup option was provided in cpanel.
I've googled it but all I could found was the php script for automatic backup using FTP on remote host.
What I'm looking for is the way to backup on the local shared host.
I've tried using [the code](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1016697) for FTP backup on remote host by changing the values to what my local shared host have but didn't work for me.
It sounds useless to keep the backup locally but that's the only option we have now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you can or cannot backup is decided by the host. You should contact their support (it's easier). I don't understand what codes are you looking for alternatively. The surest backup is to keep a copy of your files on your hard-disk and FTP is the probably the most reliable way to do it. I might be wrong but...

Comment: They said that I can backup everything. Since I want to backup locally, I don't think I have to use FTP.

Comment: well if you can backup everything, you have the backup wizard on CPanel don't you...I am not sure I am understanding your question though

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to backup to a remote FTP server, check out this [backup script generator](http://www.ericzhang.me/projects/cpanel-auto-backup/) that allows you to save backups to your local shared host (just leave the FTP server section empty)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cPanel UAPI to do that. cPanel full backup contain everything. Here is an example code for [free automated remote backup for GoDaddy](https://forum.webseodesigners.com/web-design-seo-and-hosting-f16/free-automated-remote-backup-for-godaddy-save-usd3-t3614.html).